# AES decryption with PyCryptodome does not produce the expected result

Tags: javascript, python, encoding, cryptography, aes

I have some difficulties reproducing AES encryption and decryption in python.

**Context**: A year ago, I created a small django based application using [this javascript library](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js) for **client side encryption**. Basically, some users' inputs are encrypted with a key and sent as hexadecimal strings to be stored.

For the illustration, I'll focus on `bd45bcccd0` (a.k.a '*Masha*' encrypted with john's key: `3ed8bd71327aafd855aac37921519767`)

### Encryption and decryption with the current js library

- **encryption** utf-8 -> bytes -> encrypted bytes -> hex
- **decryption** hex -> encrypted bytes -> bytes -> utf-8

`id_password` is a MD5 hash of the user's password. It is stored in the session storage and is used as a key

```js
  function encrypt(t){
    var key = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(sessionStorage.getItem("id_password"));
    var textBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(t);
    var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(key);
    var encryptedBytes = aesCtr.encrypt(textBytes);
    var encryptedHex = aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
    return encryptedHex;
    }

  function decrypt(t){
    var key = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(sessionStorage.getItem("id_password"));
    var textBytes = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(t);
    var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(key);
    var decriptedBytes = aesCtr.decrypt(textBytes);
    var decrypted_utf8 = aesjs.utils.utf8.fromBytes(decriptedBytes);
    return decrypted_utf8;
    }
```

Once loaded in `key`, I get a 16 items array (So I guess a AES 128bits CTR is performed):

```js
var key = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(sessionStorage.getItem("id_password"));
console.log(key)
Array(16) [ 62, 216, 189, 113, 50, 122, 175, 216, 85, 170, … ]
```

With the current code, encryption and decryption work

### Python implementation

For unit-testing purposes, I wanted to be able to decrypt. I am using [this library](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/introduction.html). To mimic the client side as much as possible, I tried the following:

```py
john_key = "3ed8bd71327aafd855aac37921519767"
cipher = AES.new(codecs.decode(john_key,'hex_codec'), AES.MODE_CTR)
d = cipher.decrypt(codecs.decode('bd45bcccd0', 'hex_codec'))
d.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Here is the problem but I am not sure at which stage it occurs. Here is what I checked:

```py
# key's length is correct
k = codecs.decode(john_key,'hex_codec')
k
b'>\xd8\xbdq2z\xaf\xd8U\xaa\xc3y!Q\x97g'
len(k)
16
# decoded message's length is correct
d = cipher.decrypt(codecs.decode('bd45bcccd0', 'hex_codec'))
len(d)
5
```

Since I can't rely on a library I can't reproduce the results, I wonder whether I misused PyCryptodome or whether the way this javascript library implements AES CTR encryption is reliable. Any insights?

Comment: Something helpful - try pyaes - it's also written bit ricmoo, who wrote aes-js. My fav is actually Cryptography.io(url) though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR))-mode requires an [IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Initialization_vector_(IV)). Since you do not explicitly create the IV, an implicitly created IV is used. However, both codes generate different IVs, so that the decryption fails. In the Python-code, a *random* IV is generated, in the aes-js-code a *fixed* IV (1) is used.

So that the decryption is possible with the Python-code, the same IV must be used here as in the aes-js-code ([here](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js#ctr---counter-recommended) and [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-counter-module)). For this purpose:

```
cipher = AES.new(codecs.decode(john_key,'hex_codec'), AES.MODE_CTR)
```

has to be replaced by

```
counter = Counter.new(128, initial_value = 1)
cipher = AES.new(codecs.decode(john_key,'hex_codec'), AES.MODE_CTR, counter = counter)
```

which decrypts the ciphertext to *Maria* (however not *Masha*).

---

For security reasons it is mandatory for CTR that key/IV pairs may only be used once, i.e. if the same key is applied, a new IV must be generated for each encryption. The current code has the weakness that key/IV pairs would be repeated when using the same key. A better way would be to generate a random IV for each encryption, send this IV together with the ciphertext to the recipient (the IV isn't secret, so it is usually prepended to the ciphertext), where it can be used for the decryption.

Comment: I thought iv was for CBC ciphers. Good remark on pairs use, it is clearly a weakness. I'll try your solution. Thanks